# Can't have quotes in Twilio SMS

Tags: twilio, quotes

I am using Twilio to send an SMS when a stock has a certain change.  I read in the stock tickers, get the results and if they exceed certain thresholds I link the various data pieces together and send me an SMS.  The problem is there are single quotes in the msg; this makes the message unusable.  I can explain why but that's not the issue.

My code says:

```
text_alert = \symbol, change_dir, curr_price, curr_change, \curr_chg_pct, curr_dt_time
```

Printing the result yields:

> ('AAPL', '>', u'179.5500', u'-1.3900', u'-0.7682%', '29 Nov 2018 22:57:35')

I need the above without the parens and single quotes.  Getting rid of the "u" would be helpful too.

I have seen similar questions in several places and some had answers but none that worked for me. The string / tuple explanations are not clear to me.  I am just about to give up.

Comment: Dave - it seems as though you saw my post and perhaps edited it.  I'm not sure if you responded tho.  I surely appreciate any input.

Comment: Hi Fred, what language are you using here? And can you share a bit more of your code, just to give more context?

Comment: Sure, I'm using Python on a Raspberry Pi.   The code above, i.e., "text_alert = .." is the core of it.  You'll see the result with loads of single quotes and 'u'.  As soon as Twilio sees two single quotes, it considers the SMS complete so (in the case above) I get an SMS that says "AAPL", instead of the entire list of items I'm trying to get.

Comment: I'm not a python programmer, so I'm probably doing something wrong, but if I try to write a line like `text_alert = \symbol` I get `SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character`. Can you expand on how your code is written or is supposed to work? I'm guessing that `symbol` and `change_direction` are variables that correspond to strings.